# Connecting Apple Wireless Keyboard on Fedora 15

Tags: keyboard, fedora, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard

I have an Apple Wireless bluetooth keyboard that I'd like to use with my Laptop running Fedora 15. The Bluetooth GUI tool is being extremely unhelpful.

It simply shows the keyboard in the list of available devices but when I select it, the forward button remains greyed out 4 out of 5 times. (I don't think it should do that.)

When it does proceed it shows connecting to 'null' and then after a minute or so says "connecting failed".

I tried using `hidd --search`. Here is the output:

```
Searching ...
    Connecting to device 44:2A:60:E5:C5:70
Can't get device information: Operation already in progress
```

or

```
Searching ...
    Connecting to device 44:2A:60:E5:C5:70
Can't get device information: Connection timed out
```

I also tried

```
sdptool browse 44:2A:60:E5:C5:70
```

Output was:

```
Failed to connect to SDP server on 44:2A:60:E5:C5:70: Connection timed out
```

I already went through a few forums, blogs, and posts but couldn't figure out much.

- [Bug 466988 – Trouble pairing with Apple Wireless Pro Keyboard (bluetooth)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=466988)
- [Bluetooth: How to set up your Apple Wireless Keyboard](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1809#3)
- [Apple wireless keyboard and mighty mouse - FedoraForum.org](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=200542)

Here is the lsusb output for those who need it:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6400 Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 
Bluetooth)
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth
```